# who offers free rss feeds of the most recent usenet messages besides google?

Tags: rss, feed, usenet, newsgroups

Is there any site, besides groups.google, which offers a free rss feed of the most recent messages for any usenet newsgroup?
I mean a service like the following:
http://groups.google.com/group/news.groups/feeds

Comment: I assume your current internet provider does not offer Usenet as part of its service?

Comment: I'm interested in rss feeds of usenet messages, not in access to some public newserver. See my updated question.

Answer (score 2):

http://nzbindex.com is probably the best for making a RSS feed, but paid services are a lot faster and interactive.

Usenet is vast and very active in posts, so keeping up is a hard task - which is why you don't get it for free. "Releases" tend to appear on Usenet groups first before making it's way to the "open net". Plus, Unlike oneclick hosting services like Rapidshare/Depositfiles, P2P services like gnutella/emule, torrent sites like Piratebay/sumotorrents and chat/direct connect like mIRC, it's full speed connections, anonymous and unmonitored.

Answer (score 1):

"Usenet feed" usually means receiving the messages over NNTP, which Google does **not** offer.

---

Some freely accessible servers are:

- [Eternal September](http://eternal-september.org/) (previously known as motzarella.org)
- [aioe.org](http://aioe.org/)
- <s>[greatnowhere](http://reader.greatnowhere.com/)</s> (appears down at the moment?)

aioe.org is a public server, no registration needed - which means it's only useful for reading. To combat spam, posts originating from such servers are often filtered strictly or even completely rejected.

---

If all you want is binaries, good luck trying to get them for free. The disk space required for even a week's posts is way too big.

Comment: I'm interested in rss feeds of usenet messages, not in access to some public newserver. See my updated question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use yahoo pipes for the work: http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/ .
You could try usenet-replayer also.